# TypeError: jQueryxxxxxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

When first opening the mobile app homepage it returns an error

> "TypeError: Jqueryxxxxxx is not a function" although it shows the API
>   callback results
>   "jQuery111309512500500950475_1459208158307({"code":1,"msg":"Ok","details":{"data"..."
>   according to Firebug.

I have to open different app pages then return to homepage to see Featured Merchants parsed.

JS Code

```
case "page-home":
    callAjax('getFeaturedMerchant','');
    break;
case "getFeaturedMerchant":
    displayFeaturedRestaurant( data.details.data ,'list-featured');
    break;
case "getFeaturedMerchant":
    createElement('list-featured','');
    break;
```

API PHP Code

```php
public function actiongetFeaturedMerchant()
{
    $DbExt=new DbExt;  
    $DbExt->qry("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1");       

    $start=0;
    $limit=200;

    $and='';
    if (isset($this->data['restaurant_name'])){
        $and=" AND restaurant_name LIKE '".$this->data['restaurant_name']."%'";
    }

    $stmt="SELECT a.*,
    (
    select option_value
    from 
    {{option}}
    WHERE
    merchant_id=a.merchant_id
    and
    option_name='merchant_photo'
    ) as merchant_logo

    FROM
    {{view_merchant}} a
    WHERE is_featured='2'
    AND is_ready ='2'
    AND status in ('active')
    $and
    ORDER BY sort_featured ASC
    LIMIT $start,$limit     
    ";              

    if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
        dump($stmt);
    }

    if ($res=$DbExt->rst($stmt)){
        $data='';

        foreach ($res as $val) {                
            $data[]=array(
              'merchant_id'=>$val['merchant_id'],
              'restaurant_name'=>$val['restaurant_name'],
              'logo'=>AddonMobileApp::getMerchantLogo($val['merchant_id']),               
            );
        }
        $this->details=array(
          'data'=>$data
        );
        $this->code=1;$this->msg="Ok";
        $this->output();
    } else $this->msg=$this->t("No Featured Restaurant found");
    $this->output();
}
```

I'm stuck and confused what's causing this error and how to resolve it.

EDIT: Added the full callAjax Function

```
function callAjax(action,params)
{

    /*add language use parameters*/
    params+="&lang_id="+getStorage("default_lang");

    dump(ajax_url+"/"+action+"?"+params);

    ajax_request = $.ajax({
url: ajax_url+"/"+action, 
data: params,
type: 'post',                  
async: false,
dataType: 'jsonp',
timeout: 6000,
crossDomain: true,
     beforeSend: function() {
if(ajax_request != null) {      
   /*abort ajax*/
   hideAllModal();  
           ajax_request.abort();
} else { 
},
    complete: function(data) {  
ajax_request=null;           
hideAllModal();
    },
success: function (data) {    
dump(data); 
if (data.code==1){
    switch (action)
    {

   case "getFeaturedMerchant":
   displayFeaturedRestaurant( data.details.data ,'list-featured');
   //$(".result-msg").text(data.details.total+" Restaurant found");
   $(".result-msg").text(data.details.total+" "+ getTrans("Featured Restaurants found",'restaurant_found')  );
   break
    )      
    else {
    /*failed condition*/
    switch(action)
    {   
    case "getFeaturedMerchant":
    createElement('list-featured','');
    //$(".result-msg").text(data.msg);
    break;
    }
    },
    error: function (request,error) {           
        hideAllModal();     
        if ( action=="getLanguageSettings" || action=="registerMobile"){
        } else {            
            onsenAlert( getTrans("Network error has occurred please try again!",'network_error') );     
        }   
    }
}};
```

Calling URL is:

> http://domain.com/mobileapp/api/getFeaturedMerchant?

Comment: The code you provide doesn't help. The error you are getting because you have used jquery while jquery is not there or not loaded. Are you using php to render app page like traditional php website?

Comment: Please show the definition of `callAjax`.

Comment: Yes guys I'm using php to render app page. CallAjax is calling a PHP function from webserver into the API file.

Comment: I'm using Onsen UI to build the app. And callAjax() should call the function from APIcontroller.php at the webserver and return the result.

Comment: the JS codes are defined into function callAjax(action,params)

Comment: How is this related to Phonegap?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 this is a PhoneGap mobile app based on Onsen UI framework using JS & PHP

Comment: @WiTonNope Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 you've got it wrong, this has nothing related to website wrappers as you've mentioned this is totally in-app queried from web server API

Comment: @WiTonNope  I've never stated your app was a web wrapper. I am simply pointing out this could be an issue - if you are unaware of it. MANY, MANY developers have not only develop and submitted apps, but have been rejected. I trust the words of all developers when the say, "i am aware of this". -- Don't be so quick to jump to rash reactions. I'll be back in a few days to help you resolve your issue - if you have not already resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an issue with the way jQuery handles the abort method when using JSONP, which I have encountered before.

Basically, JSONP works by adding a script tag to the DOM, and adding a callback it will fire when it executes.

Unlike AJAX, the request generated by a `script` tag cannot be cancelled, so when you call `abort` like below, it only sort-of works.

```
ajax_request.abort();
```

jQuery will unset the global callback it registered, `jQuery111309512500500950475_1459208158307` in your case, but it cannot stop the script from trying to run it when it loads. Thus, when it tries to call the now-undefined function, you get the error.

Personally, I think jQuery should set, or have an option to set, these global handlers to an empty function or something instead, but it doesn't. In your case, if possible, I would recommend avoiding making the request if you only plan to abort it before sending it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Two issues I see:

1. Your code bracing is wrong leading to some unintended execution paths.
2. You are trying to call `.abort()` on a JSONP request which is not supported.  Doing so will cause the callback function to be removed BEFORE the JSONP script loads that tries to call that callback function.  The `.abort()` will stop the processing of the request, but leave you with the type of script error you see reported.

Here are the notes on the code bracing:

It appears like your code bracing is wrong so you are executing the success callback too soon.  When I put your callAjax through a code formatter, it looks like this (see the spot marked "problem area"

```
function callAjax(action, params) {

    /*add language use parameters*/
    params += "&lang_id=" + getStorage("default_lang");

    dump(ajax_url + "/" + action + "?" + params);

    ajax_request = $.ajax({
                url: ajax_url + "/" + action,
                data: params,
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                timeout: 6000,
                crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                        if (ajax_request != null) {
                            /*abort ajax*/
                            hideAllModal();
                            ajax_request.abort();
                        } else {},            // <========== problem here
                        complete: function (data) {
                                ajax_request = null;
                                hideAllModal();
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                dump(data);
                                if (data.code == 1) {
                                    switch (action) {

                                    case "getFeaturedMerchant":
                                        displayFeaturedRestaurant(data.details.data, 'list-featured');
                                        //$(".result-msg").text(data.details.total+" Restaurant found");
                                        $(".result-msg").text(data.details.total + " " + getTrans("Featured Restaurants found", 'restaurant_found'));
                                        break
                                    )    // <========== problem starts here
                                    else {
                                        /*failed condition*/
                                        switch (action) {
                                        case "getFeaturedMerchant":
                                            createElement('list-featured', '');
                                            //$(".result-msg").text(data.msg);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error: function (request, error) {
                                        hideAllModal();
                                        if (action == "getLanguageSettings" || action == "registerMobile") {} else {
                                            onsenAlert(getTrans("Network error has occurred please try again!", 'network_error'));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            };
```

Add a missing brace in the problem area and you get this.  But this is still not really correct.  The two switch statements in the `success` handler are not correct syntax so they need to be fixed too.  I think your issue is that you had some counteracting syntax errors that allowed the code to somehow run, but not execute in the proper way.

```
function callAjax(action, params) {

    /*add language use parameters*/
    params += "&lang_id=" + getStorage("default_lang");

    dump(ajax_url + "/" + action + "?" + params);

    ajax_request = $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url + "/" + action,
        data: params,
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 6000,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            if (ajax_request != null) {
                /*abort ajax*/
                hideAllModal();
                ajax_request.abort();
            }     
        },    // <======== Added this brace to close off the function
        complete: function (data) {
            ajax_request = null;
            hideAllModal();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            dump(data);
            if (data.code == 1) {
                switch (action) {

                case "getFeaturedMerchant":
                    displayFeaturedRestaurant(data.details.data, 'list-featured');
                    //$(".result-msg").text(data.details.total+" Restaurant found");
                    $(".result-msg").text(data.details.total + " " + getTrans("Featured Restaurants found", 'restaurant_found'));
                    break
                )       // <============= This is out of place and so are the next few lines
                else {
                    /*failed condition*/
                    switch (action) {
                    case "getFeaturedMerchant":
                        createElement('list-featured', '');
                        //$(".result-msg").text(data.msg);
                        break;
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, error) {
                    hideAllModal();
                    if (action == "getLanguageSettings" || action == "registerMobile") {} else {
                        onsenAlert(getTrans("Network error has occurred please try again!", 'network_error'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

One possible way to approach fixing this is to fix the missing brace in the `beforeSend:` handler, then remove most of the `success` handler code to this stub and then add back in the proper code in the success handler under a careful eye:

```
function callAjax(action, params) {

    /*add language use parameters*/
    params += "&lang_id=" + getStorage("default_lang");

    dump(ajax_url + "/" + action + "?" + params);

    ajax_request = $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url + "/" + action,
        data: params,
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 6000,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            if (ajax_request !== null) {
                /*abort ajax*/
                hideAllModal();
                ajax_request.abort();
            }     
        },    // <======== Added this brace to close off the function
        complete: function (data) {
            ajax_request = null;
            hideAllModal();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            dump(data);
            if (data.code == 1) {
               // <=========== Removed faulty code in here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Original Answer**

---

That particular error and network response looks like your client wants some data from the server.  The client (for some reason) decides that it needs to use JSONP to get the response from the server so the server is sending back JSONP, but the client code that sent the request did not properly prepare for the JSONP request by defining the appropriate callback function that the JSONP script can call.

You will either have to switch to a regular Ajax call that is not JSONP or we will have to see the details of your `callAjax()` implementation to see why the JSONP response is not working.

Comment: A function name like `jqueryxxxx` seems like it would be created automatically by `$.ajax` when using `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, that is the assumption unless `callAjax()` copied some previously used URL that was generated by an earlier jQuery call.  That's why we need to see the `callAjax()` code.  If jQuery generated that name on this call, then it would have also generated the corresponding function with that name and the error would not have shown as it does.  So something is obviously not just a normal jQuery JSONP call.

Comment: I'm using Onsen UI to build the app. And callAjax() should call the function from APIcontroller.php at the webserver and return the result.

Comment: the JS codes are defined into function callAjax(action,params)

Comment: @WiTonNope - Well, we need to know more about what callAjax is doing, where it's getting the actual URL path to use to make the Ajax call and how it's constructing that Ajax call.  It looks like Onsen UI uses AngularJS which perhaps uses a subset of jQuery so that's probably where the jQuery reference comes from.  We need to know more about call `callAjax()` is doing and how it constructs the URL it ultimately uses for the Ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated my question with the callAjax function hope it helps. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @WiTonNope - So the `callAjax()` code you added is forcing JSONP (as expected).  It is also calling `$.ajax()`.  Are you specifically including full-blown jQuery in your project or is this some jQuery subset built into AngularJS?

Comment: @jfriend00 no it's a full-blown all functions running from app.js angular is used for styling and creating inpages.

Comment: @WiTonNope - OK, I'm about to run out of things to ask without being able to sit down at a debugger, but one more thing I can think of now to look at.  When looking at the network tab in the debugger, can you post the complete and exact URL that is being sent to the server?  And, can you post the URL from more than one request (I want to see if that callback=jQueryxxxx part is either duplicated in a single request or if the same jQueryxxxx is being used in more than one request.

Comment: The jQueryxxx is automatically generated I don't thin it's duplicated.

Comment: http://domain.com/mobileapp/api/getFeaturedMerchant?callback=jQuery111304287095954101815_1459224152681&lang_id=&_=1459224152683

Comment: Adding this to a comment in fully readable form: `http://domain.com/mobileapp/api/getFeaturedMerchant?callback=jQuery111304287095954101815_1459224152681&lang_id=&_=1459224152683`

Comment: @WiTonNope - OK, I think I found a code formatting problem that was causing some callbacks to run before their time.  See what I added to my answer.  It looks like coincidence the mistake you had did not cause a syntax error.  FYI, this is a walking commercial for running code through jsHint because it flags the problem area right away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107668/discussion-between-witon-nope-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @WiTonNope - What's the status of this question?  Have you figured it out yet?